# How to apply group policy(GPO) to non-domain users on domain computers?

Tags: windows, active-directory, administration, gpo

I have domain controller and domain computer.
On domain computer I have several domain users and one local user.
I want to apply specific restrictions (user policy) to local(non-domain) users on domain computer. Currently I can only apply user policy only to domain users.
Is it possible?

I tried to add to security filter whole domain computer. It didn't apply to non-domain user.

EDIT:
I know that domain polices doesn't apply to local users. So I want to find workarounds

Answer (score 1):

You can only apply local policy to local users. Domain group policy applies to domain users and domain computers. Please note that computer policy part of the domain group policy applies to the computer, hence all users logging on to this computer (including local users) are effected from this computer part of domain group policy.

For example : A domain password policy defined in computer policy part of domain gpo will effect local users also.

If the same settings exist both in local policy and domain group policy then domain group policy overwrites.

Comment: I know that domain polices doesn't apply to local uses. There are some interesting polices like wallpaper set only working only in local polices.

Comment: I ask about workarounds to apply specify local polices to all local users.

Comment: If a setting in Computer Configuration of a LocalGPO is set then all local users will be affected unless overwritten by a DomainGPO which has the same setting in its Computer Configuration part. If your specific setting exists in Computer Configuration, the you may set it through DomainGPO which will affect all the local users of the computers to which DomainGPO is applied. If a LocalGPO is edited and a User Configuration setting is modified, it will again affect all local users unless overwritten by a DomainGPO.